# How can i get the property in the sequence they have in file

Tags: java

I am using file properties file and loop through that file.

```
Properties Config= new Properties();
Config.load(new FileInputStream("c:\\Config.properties"));
Enumeration e = Config.propertyNames();
while (e.hasMoreElements())
{ String key = (String) e.nextElement();
  System.out.println(key + " -- " + Config.getProperty(key));
}
```

My Input in C:\Config.properties is

**Input**

fun1= abc

fun2=pqr

fun3 mno

**Output**

fun2 -- pqr

fun1 -- abc

fun3 -- mno

How can i get this what exactly in the Config file.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible using [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) as it extends [`java.util.Hashtable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) which is by nature unordered.

Your best bet is reading and parsing it yourself using for example a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) or a [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

I however wonder why ordering is that important. There may be alternatives which I can only suggest if you elaborate the functional requirement behind this all in detail. Based on the given example, the closest what I can suggest you is the following:

```
List<String> funs = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    String fun = config.getProperty("fun" + i);
    if (fun == null) break;
    funs.add(fun);
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply, i am trying to pass methods from properties file it self

Comment: I still don't understand the functional requirement. Anyway, I edited the answer and added a suggestion of which I *guess* that it suits your requirement the best. It must at least give you new insights. Oh please try to respect the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Variable names starts with lowercase.

Comment: I am reading excel file and need to perform some operations column by column, eg. for Column 1 i need to call only two methods , for next column 7 methods and so on. Every time these values are changing so i am trying to make it as Congigurable

Comment: Column 1= fun1,fun3,    Column2= fun1,fun2,fun3,fun4,   Column3=fun4 only and so on

Answer (score 1):

Properties is not an ordered map so you might want to create a [SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) from the loaded properties. This guarantees that the keys are naturally ordered. But i assume you want the order to be the one that you specify in the properties file. There is no way to do it automatically. You need to code it yourself.

As BalusC suggested read line by line from beginning using file API, create a Pair/Tuple object and insert it in the List object or add it to SortedMap based upon your usage requirement

Answer (score 0):

I would be shocked if there isn't a library that already does this. Try [Apache Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/howto_properties.html), for example.